# Using hyperref with base classes

Tags: hyperref, document-classes

I am using the package `hyperref` in combination with custom base classes and I have problems understanding the error messages:
`Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \Hy@colorlink` and `Undefined control sequence. \close@pdflink ->\Hy@endcolorlink`.
They only appear when the package is declared in the document. It works as expected when declared in the base class.

Consider the following minimal setup:

```
\ProvidesClass{base}
\LoadClass{report}

% declare option 1: works
% \RequirePackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \tableofcontents
}
```

```
\documentclass{base}

% declare option 2: does not work
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  hello
  \section{Two}
  goodbye
\end{document}
```

#### Background

I have to write a series of reports for university with the same structure and would like to outsource all non-content pages into a documentclass.
`\AtBeginDocument` handles things like titlepage, abstract, table of contents, etc.

Comment: Don't do typesetting in AtBeginDocument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem doesn't need a special class, only that hyperref is loaded behind your `\AtBeginDocument` call:

```
\documentclass{report}

\AtBeginDocument{\tableofcontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  hello
  \section{Two}
  goodbye
\end{document}
```

`\AtBeginDocument` shouldn't be used to start typesetting. Lots of packages add their initialization code there.

With a new latex 2020/10/01, which can currently be tested by using the -dev version (e.g. pdflatex-dev) you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\tableofcontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  hello
  \section{Two}
  goodbye
\end{document}
```

With older latex you can use etoolbox:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{\tableofcontents}


\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  hello
  \section{Two}
  goodbye
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added some background in the post to give some clarity.
If `\AtBeginDocument` should not be used like that, what about `\AfterEndPreamble`?

Comment: Well my second example does use `\AfterEndPreamble`, so yes this is ok for this stuff, that is late enough.

Comment: There is a difference between `\AfterEndPreamble` and `\AtEndPreamble`

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was testing `\AtEndPreamble`, which was not tale enough I suppose.